# Composite functions with more complicated functions

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I have this question, as below, and I cannot understand what I am being asked of. Typically I would consider the composition of functions to be rather simple, such as $f(x)=2x-5$ $g(x)=x-2$, therefore $f(g(x))=2x-9$. However, this question does not resemble that of what I am familiar with.

> Let $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$. The functions $f$ and $g$ (from the set $X$ to the set $X$) are $f=\{[1,2],[2,2],[3,4],[4,3]\}$ and $g=\{[1,3],[2,1],[3,4],[4,1]\}$. Determine the compositions $f∘g$ and $g∘f$. Give your answers in the same form as $f$ and $g$ above.
> The composed function $f∘g$ is the function that at the point $x$ gets the value $f(g(x))$. The notation above for the functions $f$ and $g$ means that, for example, $f(2)=2$.

Can someone please explain what '$f=\{[1,2],[2,2],[3,4],[4,3]\}$' means and then how to begin finding the composition between these two functions.

Comment: It means that $f(1)=2, f(2)=2, f(3)=4, f(4)=3$.

Comment: If you remember about relations defined on a set, then you will know that functions are special kinds of relations. Relations are often written as a set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ which denotes that $x$ is related to $y$. In the case of a function, this relation is the function itself i.e. $(x,y)\in f\Leftrightarrow x\mapsto y$ under $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function can be given as a set of ordered pairs. The function you write as "$f(x)=2x-5$", if we don't mind restricting its domain to a small set, say $\{0,1,2\}$, can be expressed as $f=\{[0,-5],[1,-3],[2,-1]\}$. This is just a compact way of giving us the values of $f$ for each domain point.

In your example, you want to write $f\circ g$ in the same way. Thus, you want to write:

$f\circ g=\{[1,f(g(1))],[2,f(g(2))],[3,f(g(3))],[4,f(g(4))]\}$

Each of those second elements in the pairs must be calculated, so for example, $f(g(1))=f(3)=4$. We know that $g(1)=3$, because $g$ includes the pair $[1,3]$, and likewise for $f(3)$. Consequently, the first pair in the set defining $f\circ g$ should be $[1,4]$.

Does that clarify what's being asked here?

Comment: Yes, it does a very good job. Thanks.

Comment: I have followed through with this, slightly confused with working each out but would be great if you could have a look over them. f∘g={[1,4],[2,2],[4,3],[1,2]} and g∘f {[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,4]}

Comment: This is partly correct. Remember that, for $f\circ g$, you need to apply $g$ to the input first, and then $f$ to the output of that. Consider the input $4$: We have $g:4\mapsto 1$, and then $f:1\mapsto 2$. Therefore $f\circ g:4\mapsto 2$.